# Can MySql 5.0 have a view of a table located on another server

Tags: mysql, view

Can MySql 5.0 views use tables that are located on another server?  What is the syntax for creating such a view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Federated Tables:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

This allows a table to be remotely accessed as if the remote table was a local table. It has its limitations but seems to meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create objects in one database that reference another database and even another host. The syntax to do so works something like this:

```
USE localhost.myDB;

SELECT * FROM host2.db.tableName;
```