# How split MySQL database into multiple host, keeping remote references

Tags: mysql, database-design, remote-access

I'm developing a web application that will handle user and data.
One requirement for this project is that the data collected must be stored in another host than the one with webserver.

My first idea was to deploy a single database with user data, login info and preferences all together into one host and keep the webserver into another one, using remote connection for each query. But this is not required, only user data must be stored in a remote host and other info can be locally accessed by webserver.

Does exists a way to manually split a MySQL database in two different host leaving to the framework to keep remote reference and coherence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this:

[Can MySql 5.0 have a view of a table located on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178401/can-mysql-5-0-have-a-view-of-a-table-located-on-another-server)

In the local DB define the view of the table you want to be remotelly hosted.